# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.pyrfc'; '__main__' is not a package

Tags: python, json, odoo, saprfc, pyrfc

I already install

```
C:\Python37>pip3 install pyrfc`
```

my output like this.

```
Collecting pyrfc
  Downloading pyrfc-0.1.2.tar.gz (3.5 kB)
Installing collected packages: pyrfc
    Running setup.py install for pyrfc ... done
Successfully installed pyrfc-0.1.2
```

but when import I see this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from .pyrfc import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.pyrfc'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Comment: Did you try linking the package

Comment: sorry how_linking the packag

Comment: Are you using virtual environments? Is that the entire error?

Comment: no i use physical

Comment: try `pip freeze`and `python -v` and check if pynwrfc module is being loaded at all. Try to reinstall it in the user dir: `pip3 install --user pynwrfc --no-binary :all:`